# Edit myaccount navigation menu edit adresses link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have a woocommerce site with only billing details, so i dont really need the "https://www.lawrence.dk/my-account/edit-address/" link, i would rather it went directly to https://www.lawrence.dk/my-account/edit-address/billing/ however i cant seem to find any way to do so.

How do i edit the myaccount navigation link so it goes directly to that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ) {
    // DEBUG INFO (uncomment if needed)
    //echo '<pre> 1. ', print_r($url, 1), '</pre>';
    //echo '<pre> 2. ', print_r($endpoint, 1), '</pre>';
    //echo '<pre> 3. ', print_r($value, 1), '</pre>';
    //echo '<pre> 4. ', print_r($permalink, 1), '</pre>';

    if( $endpoint === 'edit-address' ) {     
        // Custom URL
        $url = site_url() . '/my-account/edit-address/billing/';     
    }

    return $url;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 10, 4 );
```